# com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error Code 4: Parameter error

Tags: java, aerospike

when I want to put in aerospike through this method

```
public void putIsMentionedInMsg(String key, boolean isMentioned) {
    try {
        if (isActive() ) {
            final WritePolicy TOKEN_WRITE_POLICY = new WritePolicy();
            TOKEN_WRITE_POLICY.expiration = (int) Settings.MENTIONED_IN_MESSAGE_EXPIRE_DURATION / 1000;
            TOKEN_WRITE_POLICY.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.REPLACE;
            TOKEN_WRITE_POLICY.commitLevel = CommitLevel.COMMIT_MASTER;
            getClient().put(
                    TOKEN_WRITE_POLICY,
                    getKey(ChatSettings.MENTIONED_IN_MESSAGE_SET_NAME, Value.get(key)),
                    new Bin("key", key)
                    new Bin("value", isMentioned)
            );
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.warn("An exception occurred", e);
    }
}
```

and the getKey method is:

```
   Key getKey(String setName, Value value) {
        return new Key(Settings.AEROSPIKE_NAMESPACE, setName, value);
    }
```

I got this error:

```
com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error Code 4: Parameter error
    at com.aerospike.client.command.WriteCommand.parseResult(WriteCommand.java:54)
    at com.aerospike.client.command.SyncCommand.execute(SyncCommand.java:82)
```

As the value is a primitive boolean it's always true or false and never null. so there is no null value for REPLACE policy

Answer (score 2):

1 - What is the namespace in getKey()? Hard to diagnose without your code for getKey() - but looks like you may not be forming the Key Object correctly unless in getKey() you have a namespace hardcoded.

2 - In `new Bin("key", key)` ... key is type String, constructor expects type Value. So use `Value.get(key)`. Likewise for the next Bin, `Value.get(value)`.

Comment: I even changed the 
TOKEN_WRITE_POLICY.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.UPDATE
but I still got the exception

Comment: the getKey method has been added to the question description. I am going to remove the new Bin ("key", key). it seems rational to have a bin with the name "key" makes it ambiguous

Comment: -->   new Bin("key", Value.get(key)), new Bin("value", Value.get(value))

Comment: Does the server log have any interesting entry corresponding to this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the [bin convergence](https://docs.aerospike.com/server/operations/configure/cross-datacenter/bin_convergence#record-replace-not-allowed) feature is enabled on your Aerospike cluster. If so, use the `operate` API instead of `put`.